# Is there a generic, recursive flask template?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

As a way to rapidly prototype an html ui, I am looking for a generic jinja2 template, that will display an object's or dictionary name/value pairs recursively, including drilling into sub objects recursively.

So say I had this dictionary:

```
a_dict = {'name1': 'value1', 'name2': 'value2'}
a_dict['other'] = {'name3': 'value3', 'name4': 'value4'}
```

It would display something like this:

```
name1: value1
name2: value2
other:
    name3: value3
    name4: value4
```

Comment: what do you mean by objects? give an example

Comment: go look at jinja macros. I am gonna go eat but if you havent figured it out by then I help you with the answer :)
[good guide for jinja macros](http://davedash.com/tutorial/jinja-macros/)

Comment: Got a start on it, but not sure yet how to decide to recurse (i.e. when is a value a value vs a sub-object or dictionary). https://gist.github.com/dkackman/5ed5862ecc96bf0c6d68477063a92d2b

Comment: you can use filters to get the object type
https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/templating/#registering-filters

Comment: give me 20 more minutes and i can help

Comment: cool - having trouble registering the filter. (new to both python an djinja)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207956/discussion-between-dontbe3greedy-and-dkackman).

Answer (score 1):

```
{% macro show_node(node) %}
   {% for key, value in node.__dict__.items() %}
        <span>{{key}}: </span>
        {% if value is mapping %} <-- not sure what to do here
            {{ show_node(value) }}

        {%else%}
            <span>Value: {{value}}</span>
        {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}
{% endmacro %}
```

there you go